# kubernetes - where is the official api documentation that says whether matchLabels is mandatory or not

Tags: kubernetes

Today I was going through some documentation and discussions about matchLabels statement that is a part of a Deployment (or other objects) in Kubernetes. Example below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

In some discussions, I saw that depending on the version of the API it could be optional or mandatory to use this selector.

Ref:

https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/7680

[What is the purpose of a kubernetes deployment pod selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309057/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-kubernetes-deployment-pod-selector)

But I can't see any official documentation where it is stated explicitly if the usage of this selector was mandatory or not for a specific version of a Kubernetes API. Do you know of any official documentation where it is stated whether or not it is mandatory to use matchLabels selector?

I have checked these links out but I did not bump into an official statement:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#deploymentspec-v1beta2-apps

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kubectl explain deploy.spec.selector --api-version=apps/v1`

> Label selector for pods. Existing ReplicaSets whose pods are selected
>   by
>        this will be the ones affected by this deployment. It must match the pod
>        template's labels.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/api/apps/v1/types.go#L276-L279

> ```
> Selector *metav1.LabelSelector `json:"selector" protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=selector"`
> ```

The lack of `+optional` above this line tells you it's mandatory. It matches up with the error message you'll get if you try to make a deployment without one.

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
 spec:
   replicas: 1
   template:
     spec:
       containers:
       - image: nginx
         imagePullPolicy: Always
         name: nginx
       dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
       restartPolicy: Always
EOF
```

> error: error validating "STDIN": 
>   in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec; if you choose to ignore these
>   errors, turn validation off with --validate=false. error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing
>   required field "selector"

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1/types.go#L1076-L1085

```
type LabelSelector struct {
    // matchLabels is a map of {key,value} pairs. A single {key,value} in the matchLabels
    // map is equivalent to an element of matchExpressions, whose key field is "key", the
    // operator is "In", and the values array contains only "value". The requirements are ANDed.
    // +optional
    MatchLabels map[string]string `json:"matchLabels,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,1,rep,name=matchLabels"`
    // matchExpressions is a list of label selector requirements. The requirements are ANDed.
    // +optional
    MatchExpressions []LabelSelectorRequirement `json:"matchExpressions,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,2,rep,name=matchExpressions"`
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks. But this says nothing about whether matchLabel usage is mandatory or not.

Comment: wonderful. But the error message you mentioned above tells me it is actually possible to suppress the validation and create a deployment without specifying this selector. I understand that not having the "// +optional" comment in the code implies it is NOT an optional parameter but still not solid proof since is it just a comment.

Comment: I don't know GoLong so I had to do a little bit of quick reading. Apparently, for the fields which are NOT required (optional) in a struct we use ",omitempty" tag. Observing the piece of code you referred to at the FIRST link, all the optional fields have this ",omitempty" tag but "Selector" does not have this tag. This is actually the solid proof that 'Selector" is NOT optional. Now, we see the proof in the code. Although I was looking for an official documentation this is also as good. Answer accepted. Thanks!