# Why does kubenertes deployment require selector label?

Tags: kubernetes

Hi I'm new to kubernetes and I am confused on the label and selector objects. In a Kubernetes Deployment object, why is selector required when the pod template is already defined in the spec? Its like telling a farmer to plant oranges when he only have orange seeds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of a kubernetes deployment pod selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309057/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-kubernetes-deployment-pod-selector)

Comment: Oh yes. I guess my question is a duplicate then. Feel free to mark it as a duplicate.